# how do I use node.js with formidable and socket.io on progress status for each file uploaded?

Tags: socket.io

I'm trying to figure out how to send upload data progress back to client.
it seems this event executed twice and it carries previous progress.

form.addListener('progress', function(bytesReceived, bytesExpected) {

```
            socket.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {

                socket.emit('Uploaded', {
                    progress : (bytesReceived / bytesExpected * 100).toFixed(0)
                });
            });

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send the socket.io connection id together with your file upload request. You can get it from the client code like this:

```
var socketio = io.connect();
// more code here
// once connected you can access the following prop:
console.log(socketio.socket.sessionid);
```

Once you have received that `socket.sessionid` on the serverside you can look up the connection and emit the data

```
io.sockets.socket(id).emit('uploaded', dataz);
```

Hope this helps.